# Check whether a coin is fair

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

An interview problem is like the following:

> Given a coin you don’t know it’s fair or unfair. Throw it 6 times and 
>   get 1 tail and 5 head. Determine whether it’s fair or not. What’s your
>   confidence value?

I came out the following solution:

> $H_0:$ the coin is fair
>   $H_a:$ the coin is unfair
>
> $X$: is the number of heads
>
> Rejection region: $|X - 3| > 2$, i.e., $X = 0,1,5,6$
>
> Significance level alpha:
>
> $\alpha = P(\text{reject }H_0 \mid H_0 \text{ is true})$
>   $=P(X=0,1,5,6 \mid H_0 \text{ is true})$
>   $= (\binom{6}{0}+\binom{6}{1}+\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{6})*(1/2)^6$ 
>   $= (1+6+6+1)*(0.5^6) = 0.21875$
>
> because $\alpha > 0.05$, we do not have enough evidence to reject $H_0$, and
>   we  accept $H_0$, so the coin is fair

Is the above test a good one? And I did not know how to calculate the confidence value?

Comment: @Tim, no, it's an interview question

Comment: It still falls into self-study category, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: While I spend a lot of text explaining why a hypothesis test won't answer the question that was asked and indeed why no amount of data can be used to demonstrate that the coin is actually fair, I've added a section at the end explaining several things wrong in your attempted hypothesis test. (If you actually said those things in the interview, I expect you didn't get the job, because some of those errors are fundamental.)

Comment: If you want to learn more about coins per se (following @Glen_b comment and answer) check this thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153076/is-tossing-a-coin-a-fair-way-of-randomising-a-group-into-two-groups/153080#153080

Answer (score 11):

[I think I'd start by asking for a whiteboard, markers -- and an eraser, because one boardful isn't enough to explain everything wrong with the question.]

I'm going to answer this question by rejecting its premises.

1. The "coin" itself is just a coin; by itself it doesn't do anything, and so it cannot be fair or not-fair. What we're talking about is the process of tossing a particular coin in some fashion -- *that* can be discussed in terms of whether it's fair or not.
2. Data can't show you that a coin-tossing process applied to some coin is exactly *fair*. Sometimes it can show you that your coin-tossing-process on a given coin is inconsistent with fairness, but failure to identify any inconsistency with fairness doesn't imply fairness (failure to reject is because your sample size is small, not because the coin is actually fair).

   [e.g. Consider it in terms of a confidence interval for P(head), the fact that $\frac12$ is in the CI doesn't mean that P(head)=$\frac12$, since there are always other values - distinct from $\frac12$ - in there too. Or think in terms of power: on the experiment given in the interview question - 6 tosses - what's the probability that you'd reject as unfair the case where the tossing process applied to a particular coin had $p(\text{head})=0.51$ at some typical significance level? That's clearly an unfair coin, but you'll reject barely more often than your type I error rate, and a large fraction of those rejections in a two tailed test would be "in the wrong tail"!]
3. No coin-tossing process on a given coin will be *perfectly* fair. (For example, changing the side facing up slightly alters the chances associated with the resulting face on the toss, as experiments run by Persi Diaconis have shown.)

   Could the coin be *close to fair*? Possibly; it may even be possible to get *very* close to fair. *Exactly fair?* No, it's not possible in practice. But then to discuss whether it's "close to fair" we'd have to define what we mean by 'close'. [If we were to give some usable definition, while some people might suggest some form of equivalence test, or perhaps considering whether some CI lay entirely inside some "close to fair" bounds, I'd be inclined toward a Bayesian approach to deciding whether the coin is sufficiently close to fair. Note that with the tiny sample size mentioned, the data are quite consistent with p(head) so far from $\frac{1}{2}$ that this exercise on that data would not conclude "close to fair" on any of the three mentioned approaches.]

So:

> Given a coin you don’t know it’s fair or unfair.

Yes, actually, I do. In fact I don't even need to see data. It's not fair.

> Throw it 6 times and get 1 tail and 5 heads. Determine whether it’s fair or not.

I really don't care what the data are. It makes no difference to my answer, since the data could not possibly demonstrate fairness, even if fairness were a realistically possible state to be in.

> What’s your confidence value?

100% (in a sense similar to *almost surely*)

(In any case, even if there were a way to do this statistically I don't know of any statistical procedure that gives anything I'd agree to call "confidence values", so I also reject the form of that question. What does that term even mean? If I were asked a question phrased that way in an interview, I'd have serious concerns about working there, because it seems to suggest the people conducting the interview don't really understand what they're even asking - and that suggests either nobody there knows this stuff, or they don't care enough about this position to make sure the interview is being conducted by someone who does. Either way, it would certainly influence my willingness to work there.)

---

Forgetting everything I just said for the moment, some comments on your hypothesis test:

Your process for a hypothesis test is wrong.

1. Why do you compare your *significance level* with 0.05? You've chosen a significance level of 0.21 (which I have no objection to in this experiment, the sample size is so low you only have 3% or 21% and $\alpha$=3% will be too low-powered to be much use) -- 0.05 doesn't relate to *anything* here.
2. Do you see that in your test when it came time to reject or not reject, you made no reference at all to the *sample* statistic (5 heads)? Indeed you ignored your rejection rule.
3. The rejection rule you stated algebraically $|X-3|>2$ is inconsistent with the rejection region you mentioned ($0,1,5,6$).

That's a lot of errors in a few lines! If I was involved in such an interview**, I might forgive the error with the rejection rule as something one could overlook under interview pressure, but the first two errors would suggest some fundamental problems.

** leaving aside that I'd never ask such a poor question, nor would I likely care enough about hypothesis testing to even think to ask a question about it.

Comment: As you know I take your posts as free tuition, and read them with attention. That's why I want to ask you if elaborating on possible Bayesian prior assumptions, and resulting posterior pdf's as [in this code](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/BAYES) I compile from a youtube quoted in the github file would be meritorious.

Comment: @Antoni Are you asking if you should post an answer to that effect? If so, I'd say "yes, there might be value in that" (but keeping in mind generally people will get value from plots and an outline of the approach rather than from reading the code; you'll still at least want to point to code of course, or include it if it's short enough). ... ctd

Comment: ctd... On the other hand, if you're asking if I'd like to change my answer to do so, I don't think so, at least not at this point, but I'd think about it (for that second option, however, I have added a little to my parenthetic comment after item 3, to explain why on the data in the question the result is obvious for the "is the coin close to fair" question - we simply can't conclude that it is.]

Comment: You read me well on your first reply. I was thinking of writing something when I read "bayesian" on your original answer, which was very clear from the beginning, but reminded me of the source I quoted. I didn't know if something along the lines of the code on github made sense. I'll work on it, and see what comes out. Thank you!

Comment: +1 on this answer for the middle section.  I don't understand what the first point is about?  Doesn't calling a coin fair mean that its bias is equal to (or is close to) $\frac12$?

Comment: @Neil G. The coin just sits there, it can't generate head or tails. You have to have some protocol and mechanism for tossing it, and it's that which determines how close to fair it is. If it's Persi Diaconis tossing the coin, then the chance it comes up heads may be close to 100% or close to 0% (since he's skilled enough to make it come up *however he likes*). If it's an ordinary person tossing it, the chance it comes up heads is *still* not 50%, but depends slightly on which face is uppermost. Since the same coin can have a range of probabillities of coming up heads depending on exactly...ctd

Comment: ctd ... what protocol is used (does the tosser choose which face is uppermost at the start? Is it decided by *another* coin toss? ... ), and the mechanism by which it is tossed (by hand? how high? does it have to spin? by machine? how does it work? Is it the face which is uppermost when it lands or is it caught in the palm and slapped down on a surface?). So we can't talk about the p(head) for a given coin, since it doesn't have a single number. You have to condition on the coin as well as the way you get the results. Bias is a property of the *whole experiment*, not simply the coin.

Comment: [Persi demonstrating the skill of tossing heads at will](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdA7TeoZD_g#t=120s) (link should go to the two minute mark; the relevant part goes for about a minute)

Comment: +1 However, there seems to be an inconsistency, as you first claim that a coin cannot be fair or not-fair yet later you assert that "[...] In fact I don't even need to see data. _It's not fair_". Should this not be: it's neither!? The term "fair coin" seems to be rather unfortunate. As you rightly point out, it refers to a process and not a coin in and of itself. Sadly, it seems the language use can get muddled. The only way to _determine_ the fairness of a process is to simply examine the generating mechanism itself (which in real world could be very difficult, but is conceivable).

Comment: @Graeme There's definitely some looseness there, but the point I was attempting to make is that in practice a process cannot be perfectly fair.

Comment: But seriously what would you do if you are asked such a question in an interview?

Comment: Quite seriously - I explained above: "I think I'd start by asking for a whiteboard, markers -- and an eraser, because one boardful isn't enough to explain everything wrong with the question." and then start to explain. If me explaining the logical and practical problems with the question is not what they want they'd better pick someone who wouldn't try to clarify  poorly framed questions from people who should know better (otherwise they have no business conducting a technical interview). If they ask me instead about how to respond to a client who asks such a terribly framed question, ...ctd

Comment: ctd... that response would be considerably more diplomatic but still would not avoid correcting misconceptions and asking for clarification of what the client wanted. Does explaining the problem with the question (and then seeking clarification) make me a poor prospect for some jobs? *I certainly hope so*. A job interview isn't just about them seeing if I fit them, it's also about whether they fit me.

Comment: I kid not one whit about the whiteboard, markers and eraser and the ensuing explanation (though details may vary in practice, depending on the exact circumstances); I am not in the least intimidated by explaining considerably more complicated statistical ideas than the ones here, in the moment, to a group of people of varying abilities. I have done more or less similar things in a very wide variety of situations to many different audiences. Compared to a PhD defense, say, this would be relatively easy.

Comment: I could them explain an answer to a better framed question, but I'd seek confirmation that it was actually answering what they wanted first, or it could just be wasting time.

Answer (score 3):

I am not going to attempt to provide final answers to your question; I believe the topic is more than addressed after the comprehensive response given by Glen. However, and apropos of his comment about a Bayesian approach, I'd like to post some illustrations about the way our preconceptions about the "fairness" of the coin (or the experiment in general) affects the **posterior probability density**, i.e. the $p\,(\theta\,\vert\,\text{Data})$, where $\theta$ stands for the probability of heads in the coin toss.

Luckily, we have a [conjugate prior distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for the binomial case that occupies us - the beta distribution, facilitating the calculation of the posterior distribution.

```
First scenario - The Fair-Minded Player:
```

We walk into the game (not a very exciting game, but still...), and we have absolutely no reason to assume that there is foul play going on. Things being by nature less than perfect, we have it in our mind that the coin is fair-*ish*. In other words, we think that the probability of heads, $\theta$, falls somewhere around $\frac{1}{2}$. Later, the unexpected single tail out of $6$ tosses, will force us to move the posterior probability of $\theta$ to the left (the arrows indicate the influence of the data on the prior distribution):

[image]

```
Second Scenario - The Shrewd Player:
```

We strongly suspect from insider's leaked information that the game is markedly biased towards tails, and we not only are about to make a killing, but also in need to further reinforce our conviction after the first round, doubling down our bet:

[image]

```
Third Scenario - Losing Your Shirt:
```

We've never played before, but we have read a manual, and we feel ready. All signs clearly indicate that the coin is markedly biased towards $heads$, a mistake that we will soon start to correct at a high $\ $\$ cost:

[image]

```
Fourth Scenario - No Idea Whatsoever:
```

It's a good thing that the $\beta(1,1)$ distribution turns into a $U\,(0,1)$ to address this scenario, where only the *likelihood* will influence the -*posterior* probability of $\theta$. As brought up to my attention, a [Jeffreys prior is close and possibly more correct](https://tamino.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/prior-knowledge/):

[image]

So I hope this provides a bit of a light-hearted visual depiction of our approach to estimating the chances of this game being rigged, perhaps encapsulating more of a real scenario than calculations of the type `pbinom(1, 6, 0.5)`. If you want the code in R, and the credits to a great video with Matlab illustrations, [I posted it here](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/BAYES%20FAIR%20COIN).

Comment: No idea whatsover is the Jeffreys prior — not the uniform prior.

Comment: @NeilG Can you help me come up with a better term for the uniform? Ty btw

Comment: Use a Beta distribution with both parameters equal to $\frac12$.  If you're interested in exploring this topic on your own, you can try to draw all the same graphs you drew in a different parametrization.  For example, assume that you've landed on an alien planet who think of probability on a $\ell \in (-\infty, \infty)$ scale whereby $\ell = \log \frac{p}{1-p}$.  You'll find that if you use an improper uniform prior in that space, you will end up with a different maximum likelihood value.

Comment: (my apologies, a different maximum a posteriori value).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking using chi square to measure the statistical difference between categorical variables.

Null hypothesis: half of the coins you tossed are heads and half are tails.
Alternative hypothesis: opposite to the above

Then you calculate the chi square using this formula sum((f0-fe)^2/fe) where f0 is your statistic or point estimate and fe is the expected value. And then you compare this value with critical chi square value given from table to determine if you reject null hypothesis.

Comment: With such a small sample it is invalid to use a chi-squared distribution to compute the critical value, so how do you propose computing it?