# How to generate a random number from normal distribution (not allowed to use built in functions)

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, random-generation

> Hint: To generate this number you could perform the experiment of tossing fair coin 10 times.

I guess we are supposed to use the normal approximation to binomial distribution. But I'm stuck after that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean to say you are generating a RNG *for* a normal distribution? Most RNGs generate data from a uniform (0,1) distribution based on some modular truncation of system time. Are you not using this either?

Comment: "Hint: To generate this number you could perform the experiment of tossing fair coin 10 times. "  - does the presence of some hint mean that it is a home excersize?

Comment: It seems that this is a homework, so please check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Yes it is. Why is it wrong to put it here after putting a lot of thought to it and trying the problem?

Comment: @julie It is not wrong. As you could read on the wiki page, our policy with homework problems here is that you need to specify where are you stuck and what kind of help do you need from us? What is unclear for you?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm

Comment: One clever way was published by Francis Galton in 1890.  He proposed using six specially-labeled dice.  See http://galton.org/bib/JournalItem.aspx_action=view_id=193 for a link to his paper, which contains a complete description and illustration.

Comment: @whuber That's neat. As might be expected from the method used, it [works fairly well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlMTT.png)

Comment: @Glen_b Do you have a source for that image? I wonder if it might be a good fit for [my answer to another question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/247250/22228). (In fact I wonder whether the questions are sufficiently similar as to be duplicates.)

Comment: @Silverfish by chance I still had it. Posted to ten fold